# Convergence Serie

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_{n})_{n} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $(b_{n})_{n} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $(c_{n})_{n} \subseteq \mathbb{R}_{*}^{+}$ such that exists positive constants $k$ and $\lambda <1$ where  $\frac{|a_{n}|}{c_{n}}< k\lambda^{n}$ and  $\frac{|b_{n}|}{c_{n}}< k\lambda^{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

So we can consider $\alpha^{2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a_{n})^{2}}{(c_{n})^{2}}$ and  $\beta^{2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(b_{n})^{2}}{(c_{n})^{2}}$.

Show that

$\alpha.\beta = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}b_{n}}{(c_{n})^{2}}$

I have no idea how to attack this question.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's false :

- take $a_n = \lambda^n$ if $n$ is even and 0 if it's odd.
- take $b_n = \lambda^n$ if $n$ is odd and 0 if it's even.
- take $c_n = 1$

$\alpha^2 > 0$, $\beta^2 >0$ but $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n b_n }{c_n^2} =0$

But you still have a majoration :

If you define $a_c^N = (\frac{a_0}{c_0}, \cdots, \frac{a_N}{c_N}) \in \mathbb{R}^{N+1}$, then

$$\left| \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{a_nb_n}{c_n^2} \right| = |\langle a_c^{N}, b_c^{N}\rangle| \leq \|a_c^N\|_2\|b_c^N\|_2 = \sqrt{ \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{a_n^2}{c_n^2} } \sqrt{ \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{b_n^2}{c_n^2} } $$

And if you take $N$ to $+\infty$, you get

$$\left| \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{a_nb_n}{c_n^2} \right| \leq \sqrt{\alpha^2}\sqrt{\beta^2}$$